# While ol li style is applied to ul li?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create nested list:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ol li {
        list-style: decimal outside none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>Digit</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Circle</li>
      </ul>
      <li>Digit</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

But what I get is:

```
1. Digit
    1. Circle
2. Digit
```

Why I'm getting a "decimal" marker in unordered list? I think I apply "decimal" only to `ol li` elements, not `ul li`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector says "An li that is a descendent of an ol"

The li containing "Circle" is the grandchild of the ol, so it is a descendent.

(It *shouldn't* be a grandchild since the only permitted child elements of an `ol` are `li`s, so the `ul` should be inside an `li` (which would still make it a great-grandchild) or not inside the `ol` at all).

You might want to use the child selector `>` instead of the descendent selector (a space)